# Phaser game is not registering collisions and input - but only on my machine

Tags: phaser

I was developing a game with Phaser and the Zenva Phaser Tutorial. I did some work on it last night, checked it was working, and went to bed. This morning, it isn't working! Input (either touch or mouse click) is not working, and the player no longer collides with the floor, but rather he sinks to the bottom.

[Here is my game](https://felixdebug.neocities.org/), and [here is my git source](https://github.com/NectarineGames/PhaserGame/). I have given a GitHub link, because I'm not receiving an error, and I can't pinpoint the issue.

Other users have confirmed that my game works, [but when I run it](https://youtu.be/USc8GMEMXSg), it is not the case.

Comment: @Gnemlock What do you mean by the game is working? The Zombie sinks to the bottom of the floor and won't respond to any user input. If you visited on mobile, try on desktop.

Comment: @Gnemlock I am happy to show you a video of this. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Gnemlock https://youtu.be/USc8GMEMXSg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52345/discussion-between-felix-obrien-and-gnemlock).

Comment: @Gnemlock I see that it's working for you, but it's not working for me and I would like to have some help in understanding why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by clearing my local cache in my browser history.

Lesson learnt: clear the cache if weird localised problems happen.

Comment: I feel, as an answer, this is ironically useful. It is always important to try these things - but a lot of new users have no idea, and a lot of seasoned users may still get stuck with this seemingly illogical error. I have seen this catch out experienced developers; One of my university lecturers could not explain how this could happen, to begin with, *and he has a doctorate*. Just make sure you come back to accept the answer (If it does not let you do it now). This tells future users that this solution worked.